# How to make polymorphic and static functions coexist?

Tags: c++, templates

Or is there a way to get ResponseState::EncoderTag out of class ResponseState?

The code is shown below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MirroredMsgRespState
{
public:
    virtual ~MirroredMsgRespState(){}

    virtual uint32_t encoderTag() const = 0;
};

template<typename RespMsgT, uint32_t EncoderTag>
class ErrorAndEntryResponseState : public MirroredMsgRespState
{
public:
    uint32_t encoderTag() const override
    {
        return EncoderTag;
    }
};

using ResponseState = ErrorAndEntryResponseState<int, 48>;

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<MirroredMsgRespState> myResp = make_unique<ResponseState>();

    cout << myResp->encoderTag() << endl;         // func 1
    cout << ResponseState::encoderTag() << endl;  // func 2

    return 0;
}
```

The current implementation causes the second call to report an error

Comment: You need an object to call the method on. Do you want a static method?

Comment: Is there a way that the second call doesn't require an object?

Comment: Sure, just make two different methods. What you cannot is make the same method both polymorphic and static at the same time.

Comment: None of the function in your code have been specified as `static`.  So there is nothing to co-exist.    It is necessary to call non-static functions in the context of an object  (e.g. `myRest->encoderTag()` or `some_resp_state_object.encoderTag()`).    You can't call it without referring to that object.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a static method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MirroredMsgRespState
{
public:
    virtual ~MirroredMsgRespState(){}

    virtual uint32_t encoderTag() const = 0;
};

template<typename RespMsgT, uint32_t EncoderTag>
class ErrorAndEntryResponseState : public MirroredMsgRespState
{
public:
    static uint32_t getEncoderTag()
    {
        return EncoderTag;
    }
    uint32_t encoderTag() const override
    {
        return getEncoderTag();
    }
};

using ResponseState = ErrorAndEntryResponseState<int, 48>;

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<MirroredMsgRespState> myResp = make_unique<ResponseState>();

    cout << myResp->encoderTag() << endl;         // func 1
    cout << ResponseState::getEncoderTag() << endl;  // func 2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Though technically the static method solves the compilation problem, I'd suggest the OP think about the design of these classes and the fact that such similar names may create confusion about the _encoder_: is it the same for all `ErrorAndEntryResponseState` objects or may it vary?

Comment: @cbuchart Your comment is unclear for me. `ErrorAndEntryResponseState` is a class template. There are no _"`ErrorAndEntryResponseState` objects"_. The encoder tag is the same for all objects of the same type and may vary between objects of different types. For me it looks like there is a given interface and OP wants to implement it. I assume removing the member function is not an option.

Comment: What I mean is if `ErrorAndEntryResponseState` is instantiated (objects), then the OP will have two ways to get the encoder: one through the virtual method, and another one from the static. It's clear with your implementation it's solved (since the virtual method calls the static one), but imagine if `ErrorAndEntryResponseState` is inherited and `encoderTag` is reimplemented? then calling `getEncoderTag` from the child class will return the tag from the parent, not the one from the child. You can mark the class as final, but in general I think it may lead to confusion.

Comment: It it just a general thought, it obviously depends on OP intentions and probably many other design details not exposed in the question. Just to think about it.

Comment: @cbuchart I don't try to interpret the question. Usually it's just a simplified example and doesn't represent  the actual situation. I focus on the technical solution and assume that OP knows what they do.